Using proof by contradiction, how do I prove that for all integers $n$, the number $4n + 2$ is not divisible by 4?
I've tried reading answers for similar questions, but they all seem to involve powers, and I really haven't got the faintest clue how to translate that to my question. I would assume it uses two cases - one for positive and one for negative, but beyond that I'm a bit lost... Am I supposed to negate the question so that $4n+2$ is divisible by 2 and then prove it wrong?
I haven't done this type of question in class, so if someone could please show me the working that would be most appreciated  :)

Hint : Has the equation $4k=4n+2$ an integer solution ?

If $4n+2$ was divisible by $4$, then $4n+2-4n=2$ would be divisible by $4$, a clear contradiction.

I'm not very good at proofs, so I could be wrong here, but don't I have to prove that $4n$ is divisible by $4$? What if $4n$ is equal to an arbitrary number say $22$ (which wouldn't work but I somehow have to prove that), which would then make the equation $22+2$ which is divisible by $4$.

$4n$ is $4$ times an integer, it is trivially divisible by $4$.

@PickledPie Presumably $a$ is divisible by $b$ if there is an integer $k$ with $a=b \times k$.  Then $4n$ is divisible by $4$ because $4n=4 \times n$
